# EnemyMovement C# NavMeshAgent error

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I am trying to make the enemy move toward the player when the player gets close to the enemy. This is my script,

```c#
public float lookRadius = 10f;

    Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= lookRadius)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(target.position);
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, lookRadius);
    }
}
```

I have a NavMeshAgent but it keeps giving me an error saying "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.

Answer (score 1):

> "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.

Thats because you need to bake the NavMesh. It's essentially defining what mesh is walkable and what is not, so your agents know what they can walk on.

**How to bake NavMesh**

1. Open the navigation window. [Window > Navigation]
2. Select and mark all your walkable surface as Navigation Static (or simply tick static) in the inspector (Use the dropdown beside the static checkbox).

   - Marking an object static is a way to indicate that the object will not move at all during gameplay.
3. In the object tab, mark your currently selected mesh as walkable or not walkable.
4. When you're done, under the navigation window, in the bake tab, click bake.

   - Take note that only objects with a mesh will be taken into consideration during baking
5. Your end result should looking something like this:

[image: NavMesh baking]

The blue area represents the "walkable" areas. This blue outline will only show when you have the navigation window open and have checked the Show NavMesh checkbox in the bottom right of the scene window.

Make sure your agents are always within the blue zone during startup. SetDestination will return false if you set its destination to an area without navmesh or if it fails otherwise for any reason.